# Colloquial usage when telling time with approximates

Tags: грамматика

Is it more colloquial to use около or примерно when telling time?

about 7:15

около  (preposition)  семи пятнадцати

примерно (adverb) семь пятнадцать

о́коло пятна́дцати мину́т восьмо́го

о́коло че́тверти восьмо́го

приблизи́тельно в семь пятна́дцать

Answer (score 3):

In real life people may use virtually any form, but the most colloquial ones are:

- около четверти [восьмого]
- минут пятнадцать [восьмого] (note the inversion)

Comment: Someone just told me them like this :
around 2:15
о́коло двух пяртна́дцати 
о́коло че́тверти тре́тьего     [book way]
о́коло пятна́дцати мину́т тре́тьего
приме́рно в два пятна́дцать    [most common]

(at) 7:05
(в) семь часо́в ноль пять мину́т     [old-fashioned / book way]
(в) семь ноль пять 
(в) пять МИНУ́Т восьмо́го    [common way]

Comment: There's also 'в районе'. ''В районе половины шестого''. It's a lot more informal though...

Comment: @Kaworu - "в районе" is widely used when speaking about future events, but not when telling current time. There is a subtle distinction there.

Answer (score 1):

В разговорной речи на вопрос **который час?** чаще отвечают: ***примерно***  **че́тверть восьмо́го**, ***где-то*** **четверть восьмого**, ***приблизительно*** **четверть восьмого**.
**Семь пятнадцать** - ***точная цифра***, и говорить **около, приблизительно, примерно** ***семи/семь пятнадцати/ пятнадцать***, по-моему *не корректно*. В данном случае лучше использовать слово **четверть** (***примерно четверть восьмого, где-то четверть восьмого***), не претендующее на точность.

Answer (score 1):

Мы в жизни не говорим **примерно** и **около** с минутами и секундами. В крайнем случае **почти**. Правильнее говорить **примерно** без четверти восемь,а лучше **около** восьми, **почти** /**где‐то** восемь.

Answer (score 0):

In this context they are equal and usage of them is a matter of "mental habit" that is learned from parents or significant others and relates to mental representation of time.

- `около` means area limited by circle.
- `примерно` is an adverb from 
  `примерить` - process of measuring by overlaying one thing on
  another.
- `приблизи́тельно` means something close to
  and is    originated from `приблизить` - relocating one thing close
  to another    thing.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your variants seems natural for me, some - not. Also, it depends on context. For example, if someone asks you "What time is it?", and you don't know the exact time, you can say:

> примерно семь пятнадцать

or

> начало восьмого

If it is 7:50, you can say

> Без чего-то восемь (eight without something)

If you want to arrange a meeting, you can use all your variants (for me it seems OK). But note: `приблизительно в семь пятнадцать` is a correct answer to question "When you would like to meet?", while `приблизительно семь пятнадцать` is a correct answer to "What time is it?" (but not vise versa). The preposition `в` here makes sense. The same rule works for `примерно [в] семь пятнадцать`.